# How to add OnClickListner to CardView use with ListView

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-xml, android-cardview

I am trying to follow tutorial [Android working with Card View and Recycler View](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/). I want to attach OnClickListner to each card. I tried with many answers available on stackoverflow, but they are not working for me.There are part of my code.

### MainActivity.java

```
/**
     * Adding few albums for testing
     */
    private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2};

        Album a = new Album("附近警察局", covers[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("附近医院", covers[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 2) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 2) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### AlbumsAdapter.java

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }


    public AlbumsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Album> albumList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Album album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        //holder.count.setText(album.getNumOfSongs() + " songs");

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    }
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">



                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/love_music"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                    android:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/CardContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_dark"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/love_music"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/viewBg"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.cardview.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use setOnItemClickListener

Comment: @vinoth12594 `OnItemClickListener` isn't available in `RecyclerView`

Comment: Where's your logcat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

initialize CardView in holder class

CardView cardView;

i.e

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;
        public CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        }
    }
```

and in your Adapter class access this object and add listener

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

You need to wrap your row layout inside CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

// your row layout

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you , it really helped. I was banging my head for couple of hours and then find a genuine answer @chetan

Answer (score 0):

First, define an interface for your Click events:

```
    public static interface ViewHolderClicksIntf {
    public void onClickTypeOne();
    public void onClickTypeTwo();
}
```

then you need to have an obj of this interface type to use it to pass click events through that, also your view holder needs to implement click events listener, so your event listener will look like this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener  {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;
    private ViewHolderClicksIntf mListener;
    ....
    // then you need to pass an instance of your custom event handler to your view holder 
        public MyViewHolder(View view, ViewHolderClicksIntf listener) {
        super(view);
        mListener = listener;
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    } 
    // now you need to use the passed event handler in your click events
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          mListener.onClickTypeOne();
       }

       @Override
       public void onLongClick(View v) {
          mListener.onClickTypeTwo();
       }

}
// at last, in your adapter, you need to pass an instance of  your click handler 
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView, new ViewHolderClicksIntf{
    //...your implementation of Click type methods! 
    } );
}
```